# client_secrets.json not found in pyiinstaller

Tags: python, macos, google-drive-api, exe, pyinstaller

so I have this program in python that I want to use pyinstaller to make into an executable. It runs perfectly on its own and pyinstaller makes the executable fine but when I run the executable I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 386, in LoadClientConfigFile
File "site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 165, in loadfile
File "site-packages/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 125, in _loadfile
oauth2client.clientsecrets.InvalidClientSecretsError: ('Error opening file', 
'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "updating.py", line 17, in <module>
File "site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 113, in _decorated
File "site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 443, in GetFlow
File "site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 366, in LoadClientConfig
File "site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 388, in LoadClientConfigFile
pydrive.settings.InvalidConfigError: Invalid client secrets file ('Error 
opening file', 'client_secrets.json', 'No such file or directory', 2)
[34574] Failed to execute script updating
```

Why does this work on its own but pyinstaller doesn't catch anything until the executable is ran? I can't seem to find an answer otherwise.

Notable Info:
I'm running a Mac OS X, Mojave 10.14.2, Python Version 3.7.2. 
The client_secrets.json is from a Google Drive API, v3
The file is in my directory just like all my other files, in the same spot.

Thanks!!

Comment: More than likely the location of the client_secrets.json file relative to the python executable is different in the pyinstaller packaged app that in your dev directory.  You need to be very specific about the location of the file and resolve any relative paths.

Comment: Where would I change this?

Comment: One method would be to prompt the user for the file location.